# Add link to edit suggestion to post revision history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, revisions-list

I think it would be useful to add a link to the original edit suggestion to the post revision history (and maybe also the post timeline). As far as I can see, there are nowhere else links to the original edit suggestions than in the /review page. Even more, when a suggested edit is processed, any reference to it get lost. How would one ever backtrack it?

For example, the [2nd revision of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4996631/revisions) should have somewhere a link to this [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/5413).

Comment: Jarrod added this last week, we do not show rejects in history though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea on the timestamp of this, but this has been completed. If you [view a post's revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/79465/revisions), edits that were suggested will be indicated as such and [will link to the corresponding suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/173).

[image: Image of a sample revision history element. There is a red 'suggested' which indicates the link.]