# Why was my suggested edit rejected even though it fixed a syntax error?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I fixed a syntax error in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3279244

But it got rejected. How can I appeal to this?

Comment: Editing code is a borderline action. It's much safer to leave a comment explaining mistake to the author. Only if author is not available and mistake is too minor so you don't want to duplicate post, editing it yourself makes sense.

Comment: @DanielFischer cool! Billy - [the author](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1062992/geronimo) is still active on the site, get 50 rep and leave a comment. Case closed. :)

Comment: Left a comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163842/extending-messagebox-as-view-ext-js-4-1/12164435#comment29379288_12164435

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, the 50 rep comment threshold isn't far for the OP, so in the near future he can leave a comment in such cases.

Comment: It shouldn't have been rejected `buttons: buttons:` looks a fairly obvious error in the original to me. Ideally reviewers unsure of its technical accuracy should have skipped instead of rejecting.

Comment: FYI, the OP made the edit now @BillyTom. Thanks for the help. ;)

Comment: Just a note (not taking into account whether or not your edit will actually get accepted or not, so probably just from 2k rep onwards) - answers that you're 100% sure just have a simple **accidental** error can probably be fixed, but questions probably shouldn't be, because these errors can relate to the problem the asker is having.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't appeal rejected edits. The best thing to do in this case is to leave a comment below the post (once you have sufficient rep), pointing out what you think is a problem. Code-edits are rarely accepted.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that in the future. But as I don't have 50 rep yet I can not comment yet.

Sometimes it feels like I'm fighting windmills

Comment: @BillyTom I saw that, so I left a comment for you.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully I will pass the threshold soon.

Comment: @downvoter Did our answers miss anything? The question was if rejected edits can be appealed. They can't. Where is the problem?

Comment: I downvoted because I disagree "The best thing to do in this case is to leave a comment below the post". As Gilles points out [in this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194509/correct-way-to-deal-with-minor-detail-in-answer/194522#194522) `“Comments are not recommended for (…) suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit”.`

Comment: @MartinSmith The edit was rejected. That's the situation we're working from here. You can re-suggested edits until you're blue in the face, but you'll end up annoying others if you do. Simply leave a comment, drop in a link to your suggestion if it's complex, and let the OP change it. Simple as that.

Comment: @MartinSmith Perhaps its fair enough to disagree with my answer but this answer is a pure statement of fact, you cannot appeal, code edits are often rejected. Which of these statements are untrue? Remember this is not a feature request

Comment: @RichardTingle - Yes I was possibly over hasty downvoting this one. I interpreted the comment advice as being advice for something the OP should have done instead.

Answer (score 3):

#### Suggested edit appeals

You can ask questions on meta if you are unsure about an edit rejection, but there is no direct appeal

#### Specific Example

This edit took considerably longer than seconds to be rejected. Regardless;

This changes the meaning of the answer (possibly from being incorrect to being correct but thats by the by) and so should be a comment. All moderator actions (approving edits included) should not require technical knowledge; to know if this edit is correct or not requires that knowledge and so cannot be a suggested edit.

For example within my own work `physicsSpace.physicsSpace.doSomething();` is not a typo, so its not impossible that this was correct (although i'm sure it wasn't). Not that that's good code, but it's out there

Comment: I sometimes approve edits fixing obvious typo in languages I know but generally speaking, it's not wise to suggest such edits.

Comment: `"physicsSpace.physicsSpace.doSomething(); is not a typo"` - eww.

Comment: @Dukeling I know, I strongly regret it. It's because I have an outer wrapper that manages the graphics dependancies, which I without thinking about it called physicsSpace which contains within it the true physicsSpace that is graphics independant. Not a good excuse, I'll change it one day

Comment: Ah yes, "one day" - I have a long list of those. But I've largely accepted that I'll never get to doing them.